# How can I pass a variable from class element to class element? (C++)

Tags: c++, class

My question might not be too correct... What I mean is:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
    }

    virtual void Event()
    {
    }
};

class FirstClass : public MyClass
{
    string a; // I'm not even sure where to declare this...

public:
    FirstClass()
    {
    }

    virtual void Event()
    {
        a = "Hello"; // This is the variable that I wish to pass to the other class.
    }
};

class SecondClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    SecondClass()
    {
    }

    virtual void Event()
    {
        if (a == "Hello")
            cout << "This is what I wanted.";
    }
};
```

I hope that this makes at least a little sense...

Edit: `_This` changed to `a`.

Comment: This is definitely not clear; you want to pass data between different instances of different classes with a common parent but without having the data-exchange field in the parent class? What sense does it make? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want _This to be the same _This in the other child class. The thing is, that I don't know what's missing. What should the data-exchange field look like?

Comment: By the way, `_This` is a reserved name since it begins with `_` and an uppercase letter; you should change it to something else.

Comment: +1 to Mike for pointing out reserved names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is make SecondClass inherit from FirstClass and declare _This as protected.

```
class FirstClass : public MyClass
{
protected:
    string _This;

public:
```

and

```
class SecondClass : public FirstClass
```

What you got doesn't make sense because classes can only see members and functions from their parents (MyClass in your case).  Just because two class inherit from the same parent does not mean they have any relation or know anything about each other.

Also, `protected` means that all classes that inherit from this class will be able to see its members, but nobody else.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need something like this (for a sake of simplicity, I've omitted all the unnecessary code):

```
class Base{
public:
    ~Base(){}
protected:
    static int m_shared;
};

int Base::m_shared = -1;

class A : public Base{
public:

    void Event(){
        m_shared = 0;
    }

};

class B : public Base{
public:

    void Event(){
        if (m_shared == 0) {
            m_shared = 1;
        }
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;

    a.Event();
    b.Event();
    return 0;
}
```

To explain above, I'll explain the static data members:

*Non-static* members are unique per class instance and you can't share them between class instances. On the other side, *static* members are shared by all instances of the class.

p.s. I suggest that you read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book (especially [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern).  Also note that above code is not thread-safe.